# Hadoop On Azure C#Isotope

Tags: c#-4.0, azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

During the initial release of the HadoopOnAzure, Microsoft had provided the C#Isotope SDK as a programatic interface to the Hadoop cluster on the Azure. After the HDInsight release this is removed from the downoads. 
More over while trying with the previous version of the sdk we get a 500 - Internal Server Error.

Any idea if this services is disabled? If so whats the alternative way to programatically interface with the HDInsight Cluster on Azure?

Answer (score 1):

Oh, you can find the Microsoft .NET SDK for Hadoop in Codeplex at  http://hadoopsdk.codeplex.com.

The services are very much up and running and if you have any questions, you can also check out the MSDN forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/hdinsight/threads.